# Trying to convert jpeg to png in ASP Net Core throws GDI+ exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, gdi+, blazor-server-side, system.drawing.common

I am using the System.Drawing.Common 5.0.1 nuget package in a ASP Net Core (5) application and want to convert an image (can be jpeg, png etc.) to png (if not already png).

When the image has been uploaded successfully I try to convert it with following code (the image bytes are available in `uploadResult.FileData`):

```
byte[] imageBytes;
            if (fileExtension.ToLower() != "png")
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(uploadResult.FileData))
                {
                    using(Image image = Image.FromStream(ms))
                    {
                        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                        imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
```

It always fails on this line:
`image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);`

Exception:
`An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.Common.dll but was not handled in user code: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'`

I know that there are many posts regarding this error message on this site and they contain good answers but I believe I followed them. Also most questions use an image from the filesystem or write to it but my image is already available as byte array and I write to a memorystream - but I cannot see what's possibly causing this.

Comment: Wait... you're trying to read from a memory stream and write to the end of the same memory stream?

Comment: uahh, I think I see your point. I most likely need another memory stream as target to get the bytes of the converted image... I have to try this out.

Comment: Note that gdi+ is _explicitly_ not supported on ASP, due to too many parallel users on the webapp inevitably overflowing the hardcoded object limits in gdi+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it working, thanks to the comment of [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john) with the following approach:

```
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(uploadResult.FileData))
                {
                    using (var targetMs = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using(Image image = Image.FromStream(ms))
                        {
                            image.Save(targetMs, ImageFormat.Png);
                            imageBytes = targetMs.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Not sure if this is the best, or at least a good approach. If someone comes up with something better (especially regarding performance/memory usage) I would like to see it.